# Pade approximation

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory, semi-riemannian-geometry, pade-approximation

I am trying to model the Pade approximation of a Lorentzian graph from the taylor series.
I am trying to model PA[2/2] from taylor series expansion of order N+M=4th order of derivatives taken at the point of evaluation(x=x1).For ex:The function f(x) is expanded in taylor series up to the 4th order and compared with the coefficient of a0,a1,a2.As trying to solved, I get the coefficient in terms of a0 ,a1,a2 have orders up to 4th derivatives.Can the f(x) terms in some other expressions be replaced with the PA ratio expressions and solved further?
As of now I am continuing to evaluate  but seems very very lengthy after i put all the values of coefficients.
Hope I am going in the right direction.

Comment: Could you provide the calculations and the specific Lorentzian you're talking about, please?

Comment: The graph is simple lorentzian distribution and it's taylor expansion f(x)=f(x1)+f'(x1)(x-x1)/2+...+(f''''(x1)(x-x1)^4))/4!

Comment: (a0+a1x+a2x^2)/(1+b1x+b2x^2)=taylor expansion

Comment: Could you provide the actual lorentzian function? If not I can't do its Taylor expansion... I already know what you just said.

Comment: φ(x)=1/(πγ_c ) {1+((x-x1)/γ_c )^2 }^(-1) or  φ(x)=1/{1+(x-x1)^2/〖γ_c〗^2 }

Comment: (Let me make sure) Is it this what you mean? $$\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\gamma_c}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x-x_1}{\gamma_c}\right)^2}$$

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: I’m sorry to inform you that the only PA$[2,2]$ that approximates the lorentzian is the lorentzian itself (so dumb of me since it was pretty evident). Maybe if you try different degrees on numerator and denominator you might get  some other aproximation, but it’ll never be as precise as PA$[2,2]$ since it is the function itself. You could try approximating the lorentzian via Taylor series around $x=x_1$, but it’ll only converge for $|x-x_1|<\gamma_c$.

Comment: Can you share the calculations?